# Why does NetworkManager pushes .in-addr.arpa domains to dnsmasq when connecting to a VPN?

Tags: arch-linux, dns, networkmanager, openvpn, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup [NetworkManager/dnsmasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#DNS_management) combo on an ArchLinux box and connect to a VPN (OpenVPN). It seems to work as expected, except a bunch of weird entries in the log related to `dnsmasq`, e.g.

```
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 0.8.10.in-addr.arpa
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 0.1.10.in-addr.arpa
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 1.1.10.in-addr.arpa
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 2.1.10.in-addr.arpa
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 3.1.10.in-addr.arpa
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 4.1.10.in-addr.arpa
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 5.1.10.in-addr.arpa
using nameserver 10.1.0.1#53 for domain 6.1.10.in-addr.arpa
...
```

There're some 50 domains like these. Why does `NetworkManager` push such domains to `dnsmasq` and how are they supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in-addr.arpa and ip6.arpa domains are used for *reverse DNS.* That is, when you have an IP address and want to look up a domain name that describes it.

You can't ask DNS to give you all domains that point to this address. This is more or less impossible due to DNS information being distributed across different authorities; there is no single server that knows all domains. (There used to be a DNS opcode for inverse queries, but I don't think it was ever used.)

Instead, reverse DNS is implemented as regular queries under a specific domain underneath in-addr.arpa.

For example, if you want to make a reverse lookup for `10.1.5.7`, you transform it into a domain name which looks like this: `7.5.1.10.in-addr.arpa` and then you issue a PTR query for that. (The address itself is in reverse to match the right-to-left hierarchy in DNS delegations.)

```
# dig -x 10.1.5.7

;; ANSWER SECTION
7.5.1.10.in-addr.arpa.    PTR    fileserver01.example.com.
```

So whenever your VPN server claims routes for a specific IP address range, it also does the same for the reverse-DNS suffixes that correspond to that address range. This allows you to quickly determine (for example, whenever you use `netstat` to look at active connections) that e.g. 10.1.5.7 belongs to your file server "fileserver01.example.corp".

I assume that these domains are claimed *manually* by the VPN server, because I have never seen dnsmasq nor NetworkManager do this automatically.